# Solutions and graphs of partial integro differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, matlab, integral-transforms, integro-differential-equations

Consider
$$\partial_tu+ \partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u=0,$$
subject to the initial condition $u(x,y,0) = v(x,y)$ and the boundary conditions at the infinities, $ u(0,0,t) = u(\pm\infty,\pm\infty,t) = 0,$ where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.
To use the Sumudu Transform (ST) method, the ST of the given equation is taken as
$$\frac{1}{w}\left(\mathcal{S}[u(x,y,t)]-u(x,y,0)\right)+ \mathcal{S}\left[\partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u\right]=0,$$
which leads to
$$\mathcal{S}[u(x,y,t)]=v(x,y) - w\mathcal{S}\left[\partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u\right].$$
Applying the inverse ST leads to
$$u(x,y,t)=v(x,y) -\mathcal{S}^{-1}\left[ w\mathcal{S}\left[\partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u\right]\right].$$
Applying the property of ST, which states that
$$\mathcal{S}^{-1}\left[ w\mathcal{S}[u(t)]\right]=\int_0^tu(w)dw,$$
then the equation becomes
$$u(x,y,t)=v(x,y) -\int_0^t \left[v(x,y)\partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u\right]dw.$$

How can one complete the solution and plot the graph of the above equation?

Comment: Are you sure $u(0,0,t)=0$? Without this condition, it is straightforward to solve the PDE.

Comment: Gonçalo, please note that at the moment, the condition can either be ignored or a suitable one can be imposed to obtain the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: this is not a solution using the Sumudu transform method --- it is a solution using the Fourier transform method.

Let's assume that $u(x,y,t)$ has a Fourier transform $U(k,q,t)$, i.e.
$$
u(x,y,t)=\int U(k,q,t)e^{ikx+iqy}\,dk\,dq. \tag{1}
$$
Plugging $(1)$ into the PDE $\partial_tu+ \partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u=0$, we reduce it to the ODE $\partial_tU+(ik+Dq^2)U=0$, whose solution is
$$
U(k,q,t)=U(k,q,0)e^{-(ik+Dq^2)t}. \tag{2}
$$
Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$, together with
$$
U(k,q,0)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int u(x',y',0)e^{-ikx'-iqy'}\,dx'dy', \tag{3}
$$
we obtain
$$
u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int u(x',y',0)e^{ik(x-x'-t)+iq(y-y')-Dq^2t}dx'dy'dk\,dq. \tag{4}
$$
Integration over $k$ and $q$ yields
$$
u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int u(x',y',0)\,2\pi\delta(x-x'-t)\,
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{Dt}} e^{-\frac{(y-y')^2}{4Dt}}dx'dy'. \tag{5}
$$
Finally, using the initial condition $u(x',y',0)=v(x',y')$ and integrating over $x'$, we arrive at
$$
u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\int v(x-t,y')e^{-\frac{(y-y')^2}{4Dt}}dy'
\qquad(t>0). \tag{6}
$$

Comment: Gonçalo, using Fourier transform method looks nice.
What will be the necessary modification to consider

\begin{equation}
\partial_tu+ v(x,y)\partial_xu-D\partial_{yy}u=0,
\end{equation}
subject to the initial condition $u(x,y,0) = v(x,y).$

Comment: I have no idea. The Fourier transform method could be used in the original PDE because it has constant coefficients. I don't see how to use it in the modified PDE.